# Set a variable with information inside a file

Tags: linux, shell, variables, suse

I'm new programming in shell and I need some help with this code...

```
Buildname= test
echo $Buildname > lbuild
cbuild < lbuild
echo $cbuild
```

So echo $cbuild must display the first line in the text file created.

can someone help me with that?

Comment: This is a great site to learn bash: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/  It says advanced, but it's probably about right for many people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [read](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html)

```
read -r cbuild < filename
```

Comment: Hint :) You should mark the working/used answer as accepted by clicking the outlined "check icon" on it's left side.

Answer (score 0):

I think you either want double quotes around the test in `Buildname = test` or there is more to the script.  :-)

I took the liberty of assuming I know what you need, here's my swag at it:

```
    #! /bin/bash

    Buildname="test"
    echo $Buildname > lbuild
    cbuild=$(cat lbuild)
    echo $cbuild
```

Comment: Yeah! thanks I tried with the 2 options and both are working fine... Thanks everyone!